# source in jar file visible

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I wrote a Java program and compiled it to jar file to distribute as a library that others import into their Java program and use it. It is a kind of simple library. The problem is when one imports the jar file into Netbeans to use it in their program, the source code is fully visible. They can open the classes in the jar file and see all the source. Is Netbeans decompiling the source or how is this possible? Is there a way to prevent users from seeing the source in Netbeans or any other IDE?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822824/jar-file-prevent-access-to-source-code

Comment: Does the code include original comments and names of local variables?  If so, it's not decompiled from bytecode.

Comment: As @Wyzard said, the other possibility is that you've erroneously packaged the source code along with the compiled .class files.

Comment: No, the source is not included in the jar directly. When I unzip it, it only has *.class files in it. But, sure it contains all the comments and variables declarations, everything.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's likely that Netbeans comes preloaded with a decompiler plugin, the only thing you can do is obfuscate all the classes in your jar with a tool like [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/).

They will still be able to decompile your classes, but it will be way harder to understand what your code is actually doing (heavily dependant on the complexity of your code). Sadly, you can't simply prevent  decompilation.

Comment: Decompilation is forbidden in some countries. Just sayin'

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this happens when the jar is imported to projects on the same machine on which the jar itself is developed. I took the jar file to another PC and imported it to a project, and alas the code is not visible. It is confusing why it behaving like that. I expect it should not show the code no matter what. Thanks for the replies.